# firebase-app element in polymer doesnt update itself with databinded properties

Tags: firebase, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymerfire

I have a polymer element in the link 
https://github.com/Pancake-CMS/authentication-page/blob/master/authentication-page.html

On line 55, I have a `firebase-app` element with `config` object binded to it.

When the element `local-configurator` on line 51 gets an updates configuration, it triggers the `handleConfigChange` function which updates the `config` object.

The problems is as follows.

the `firebase-app` element doest seem to show the updated config. Or even if it gets updated properties, it doesnt seem to re-initialize the firebase app.

I am not sure what is missing in the code. I was wondering if someone could point me in the correct direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

```
The firebase-app element is used for initializing and configuring your
connection to firebase. It is permanently initialized once attached and
should not be dynamically bound.
```

With that said if you want to have a dynamic configuration for firebase-app element.  Create it yourself when the config changes and setup the object that way

```
var fapp = document.createElement("firebase-app");
fapp.authDomain = ...
```

Comment: Already tried that, it never re-initializes `firebase-app` after the `authentication-page` attaches all the elements. But thanks for the info.  That doc statement was really helpful.